# ValidateModel in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use the concept of validations using Attributes like `[Required]` in webforms. How can I achieve this since this is primarily used in Asp.Net MVC. Basically I want to use `ValidateModel` method of Controller

I want to do programmatic validation. Basically I have some XML that I parse using `XmlSerializer` but I want to make sure that the string properties do not exceed certain length. So I need to do this programmatically.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use the Data Annotations Validator Control?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DAValidation/

If you want a programmatic validation you can create your own validation logic in your BO or in your Domain class. Create a validate method that returns a list string or any custom class with the errors. Then, show the validation errors to the user.